# Откуда взялся отступ между div'aми?

Tags: html, css

У меня есть два дива - `material-list-item-icon` и `material-list-item-text`. Я НЕ задаю между ними отступ, но он есть.

Вопрос - откуда берется отступ?

```css
.material-list {
    margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.material-list-item {
    padding: 10px; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.material-list-item-icon {
    display: inline-block;
}

.material-list-item-text {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="material-list ng-scope">
            <div class="material-list-item ng-scope">
                <div class="material-list-item-icon"><img class="material-image" src="https://pp.vk.me/c626429/v626429251/31025/1CukNdQDa-M.jpg"></div>
                <div class="material-list-item-text ng-binding">1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="material-list-item ng-scope">
                <div class="material-list-item-icon"><img class="material-image" src="https://pp.vk.me/c636628/v636628495/2f5cb/sOnZ_ZNIpfc.jpg"></div>
                <div class="material-list-item-text ng-binding">2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="material-list-item ng-scope">
                <div class="material-list-item-icon"><img class="material-image" src="https://pp.vk.me/c837221/v837221670/4577/K1a81HtnbUw.jpg"></div>
                <div class="material-list-item-text ng-binding">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если коротко - то это пробелы между `</div>` и `<div>`

А если подробнее - то [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/189118/)